# serilog sinks mssqlserver doesn't write completely response body on database

Tags: c#, .net, serilog, ilogger

I'm using Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer package version 5.8.0

I'm using this configuration for create my custom columns

```
var dbColumnOptions = new ColumnOptions
{
    AdditionalDataColumns = new Collection<DataColumn>
    {
        new DataColumn {DataType = typeof(string), ColumnName = "Controller"},
        new DataColumn {DataType = typeof(string), ColumnName = "Route"},
        new DataColumn {DataType = typeof(string), ColumnName = "StatusCode"},
        new DataColumn {DataType = typeof(string), ColumnName = "Method"},
        new DataColumn {DataType = typeof(string), ColumnName = "Request"},
        new DataColumn {DataType = typeof(string), ColumnName = "Response"}
     }
};
dbColumnOptions.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.Properties);
                dbColumnOptions.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.MessageTemplate);
dbColumnOptions.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.LogEvent);
dbColumnOptions.TimeStamp.ConvertToUtc = true;

LoggerConfiguration loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
                       .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                       .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(dbLogConnection, tableName, columnOptions: dbColumnOptions, schemaName: "any", autoCreateSqlTable: true);
```

And I'm using one DelegatingHandler for catch the information of the request and response to call one API, this is my code where it's writing to SQL using serilog.

```
var requestUri = string.Empty; 
var httpVerb = string.Empty; 
var httpStatusCode = string.Empty; 
var requestBody = string.Empty; 
string responseBody = string.Empty;`

requestUri = request.RequestUri.ToString();
httpVerb = request.Method.Method;
    
if (request.Content != null)
{
    requestBody = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
    
HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    
httpStatusCode = ((int)response.StatusCode).ToString();
    
if (response.Content != null)
{
    responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
    
_logger.ForContext("Controller", "Whatever")
.ForContext("Request", requestBody)
.ForContext("Route", requestUri)
.ForContext("StatusCode", httpStatusCode)
.ForContext("Method", httpVerb)
.ForContext("Response", responseBody)
.Information("Information");
```

But the information about request body or response body it's always truncated, even if the column has NVarchar(max) as type.

[truncated response SQL SErver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E4xE.png)

I don't know why is happening, if I print in the console the information about the response or request the information is not truncated, only when it wrote on the DB.

Comment: You know that SSMS can truncate values like long strings? Try `select len(longcolumn),longcolumn from yourtable where ...`

Comment: Check the length/data type of the column that you are seeing truncated.  You probably have to update the data type/length to allow for more data to be stored, probably make it NVARCHAR(MAX).

Comment: The column len is 155,488 and the type of the column is NVARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: If the `len` is 155k then the data is there. it's just the UI truncating it